# How to Show the following converges to $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

How to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left[e^{t\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{np\vphantom{()}}}}-1-t\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{np}}-\frac{1}{2}t^2\left(\frac{1-p}{np}\right)\right]\cdot p \\+\left[e^{-t\sqrt{\frac{p}{n(1-p)}}}-1+t\cdot\sqrt{\frac{p}{n{(1-p)}}}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot t^2\left(\frac{p}{n(1-p)}\right)\right](1-p)+\left(1+\frac{t^2}{2n}\right)\right]^n$$ converges to $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$  . where $0 \leq p\leq 1$ and $t$ is a parameter which can take any real value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reacll that: $e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+o(x^{2})$ for small $x$ which corresponds to large $n$. Taking $x=t\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{np}}$ and $x=-t\sqrt{\frac{p}{n(1-p)}}$ we see that the first two terms are $o(x^{2})$. Notice also that as $n\to\infty$ we have $(1+\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n})^{n}\to e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$. So we have:

$((1+\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n})+o(t^{2}(\frac{1-p}{np}))+o(t^{2}\frac{p}{n(1-p)}))^{n}=(1+\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n})^{n}+o(t^{2}\frac{1-p}{p})+o(t^{2}\frac{p}{1-p})$

which tends to $e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$.

To make the notation simpler let $u=t\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}$ and $v=t\sqrt{\frac{p}{n(1-p)}}$. Then the limit we are interested in is:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}((e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{u^{2}}{2}\frac{1}{n})p+(e^{\frac{-v}{\sqrt{n}}}-1+\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{v^{2}}{2n})(1-p)+(1+\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n}))^{n}$

Taking exponentials it suffices to show the following tends to $\frac{t^{2}}{2}$:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln((e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{u^{2}}{2}\frac{1}{n})p+(e^{\frac{-v}{\sqrt{n}}}-1+\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{v^{2}}{2n})(1-p)+(1+\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n}))$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{\ln\bigg(\frac{(e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{u^{2}}{2}\frac{1}{n})p}{\frac{u^{2}}{n}}\frac{u^{2}}{n}+\frac{(e^{\frac{-v}{\sqrt{n}}}-1+\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{v^{2}}{2n})(1-p)}{\frac{v^{2}}{n}}\frac{v^{2}}{n}+(1+\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n})\bigg)}{(\frac{(e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{u^{2}}{2}\frac{1}{n})p}{\frac{u^{2}}{n}}\frac{u^{2}}{n}+\frac{(e^{\frac{-v}{\sqrt{n}}}-1+\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{v^{2}}{2n})(1-p)}{\frac{v^{2}}{n}}\frac{v^{2}}{n}+(\frac{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}{n}))}\bigg)\cdot$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg({(\frac{(e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}}-1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{u^{2}}{2}\frac{1}{n})p}{\frac{u^{2}}{n}}u^{2}+\frac{(e^{\frac{-v}{\sqrt{n}}}-1+\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{v^{2}}{2n})(1-p)}{\frac{v^{2}}{n}}v^{2}+(\frac{t^{2}}{2}))}\bigg)$

Notice that as $x\to0$ then $\frac{e^{x}-1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}{x^{2}}\to0$ and $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\to1$ which corresponds to $n$ tending to $\infty$. Notice that the final limit is a product of two limits. I had to separate them so that it would fit properly.

Comment: But i wanted a proof explicitly.

Comment: I hope this is explicit enough. If there is an error please inform me.

Comment: can you prove that $e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+o(x^{2})$ ...

Comment: It's one definition of $e$...

Comment: If you want to check that apply L'hopital twice.

Comment: @user71352 I put the value of x in first and second bracket as you have suggested but could not get the same result as of yours. Could you please help

Comment: There was a notational issue which I corrected by defining $v=t\sqrt{\frac{p}{n(1-p)}}$. Also make sure you don't just plug in values into the last set of brackets as I have taken the limit into an exponential and suppressed the exponential function to make notation easier. That is I used that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(x_{n})}$.

Comment: @user71352  
If you want to check that apply L'hopital twice.

Comment: @user71352.... i was trying but could not get. can you please show that thing.

Comment: By L'hopital applied twice we have:
$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x}-1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}{x^{2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x}-1-x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{2}=0$
Hence, close to $0$ we have $e^{x}\le1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\epsilon x^{2}$.